# python merge multiple json requests to a single file and save it

Tags: python, arrays, json, merge, python-requests

I know this request is a bit heavy. Not sure if anyone can help, but if so I'd appreciate it.

I'm attempting to work with XML data in python which is new to me. I'm trying to write a script that parses several json requests and combines them into one. I want to feed this file into a proprietary system every x amount of time to keep all data in a single spot up to date.

```
            {
                "items": [{
                    "id": 333512,
                    "full_name": "Flooring",
                    "instock": true,
                    "dept": "none",
                    "stockid": 4708384,
                    "commonname": "StdFloor",
                    "reorder": true
                }, {
                    "id": 3336532,
                    "full_name": "Standard Tool",
                    "instock": true,
                    "dept": "none",
                    "stockid": 4708383,
                    "commonname": "StandardTool",
                    "reorder": true
                }]
            }
```

200+ of these will come back in the initial request

first I'll need to grab the ids from each one and run a separate request to get more details for each items. I know how to run the requests, but how do i make an array with just the id's?

Once I run each of those requests I'll get back 5-6 invoice details PER item. So for example, these all belong to item id 333512 in the initial response

```
                    {
                "invoices": [{
                    "invoice_id": 10015,
                    "cusbillable": true,
                    "inventoried": false,
                    "totals": 2.0,
                    "totalswh": 0.0,
                    "title": "EarlyOrder",
                    "invoicerate": 0.0,
                    "invoicedamt": 0.0,
                    "stockcost": 0.0,
                    "remainingbudg": null
                }, {
                    "invoice_id": 10016,
                    "title": "EarlyOrder",
                    "cusbillable": true,
                    "inventoried": false,
                    "totals": 2.0,
                    "totalswh": 0.0,
                    "invoicerate": 0.0,
                    "invoicedamt": 0.0,
                    "stockcost": 0.0,
                    "remainingbudg": null
                }]
            }
```

These invoices don't have the items id in them though so when i get them back using the id in the request URL I want to ADD them to the original items list as a sub array of items id as if they came back with the original request. So each item will then have its invoices attached. I'm assuming its best to run all of the requests in sequence and create an array with the id as the names of each member?

so something like this for example is what i want to end up with something like this (but formatted correctly).

```
            [{
                    "items": [{
                        "id": 333512,
                        "full_name": "Flooring",
                        "instock": true,
                        "dept": "none",
                        "stockid": 4708384,
                        "commonname": "StdFloor",
                        "reorder": true"
                            {
                            "invoices": [{
                                    "invoice_id": 10015,
                                    "cusbillable": true,
                                    "inventoried": false,
                                    "totals": 2.0,
                                    "totalswh": 0.0,
                                    "title": "EarlyOrder",
                                    "invoicerate": 0.0,
                                    "invoicedamt": 0.0,
                                    "stockcost": 0.0,
                                    "remainingbudg": null
                                },
                                {
                                    "invoice_id": 10016,
                                    "title": "EarlyOrder",
                                    "cusbillable": true,
                                    "inventoried": false,
                                    "totals": 2.0,
                                    "totalswh": 0.0,
                                    "invoicerate": 0.0,
                                    "invoicedamt": 0.0,
                                    "stockcost": 0.0,
                                    "remainingbudg": null
                                }],
                            }
                        }],
                        {
                        "id": 3336532,
                        "full_name": "Standard Tool",
                        "instock": true,
                        "dept": "none",
                        "stockid": 4708383,
                        "commonname": "StandardTool",
                        "reorder": true"
                            {
                            "invoices": [{
                                    "invoice_id": 10015,
                                    "cusbillable": true,
                                    "inventoried": false,
                                    "totals": 2.0,
                                    "totalswh": 0.0,
                                    "title": "EarlyOrder",
                                    "invoicerate": 0.0,
                                    "invoicedamt": 0.0,
                                    "stockcost": 0.0,
                                    "remainingbudg": null
                                },
                                {
                                    "invoice_id": 10016,
                                    "title": "EarlyOrder",
                                    "cusbillable": true,
                                    "inventoried": false,
                                    "totals": 2.0,
                                    "totalswh": 0.0,
                                    "invoicerate": 0.0,
                                    "invoicedamt": 0.0,
                                    "stockcost": 0.0,
                                    "remainingbudg": null
                                }],
                            }
            }]
```

Comment: so what have you tried so far and not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Principe answer about how to compile items and invoices data into a single dictionary :

```
# The container for compiled items/invoices
items = {}

# Process an items request
for data in jsondata["items"]:
    items[data["id"]] = data
    items[data["id"]]["invoices"] = {}

# Process an invoices request
id = # Your way to get the associated id
items[id]["invoices"] = jsondata["invoices"]
```

Hope it will helps you.